# Apache Camel: how to consume messages from two or more JMS queues

Tags: apache-camel

From a programming point of view, I have a very simple business case. However, I can't figure out how to implement it using Apache Camel... Well, I have 2 JMS queues: one to receive commands, another - to store large number of message which should be delivered to external system in a batches of 1000 or less.

Here is the concept message exchange algorithm:

1. upon receiving a command message in 1st JMS queue I prepare XML
   message
2. Send the XML message to external SOAP Web Service to obtain a usertoken
3. Using the usertoken, prepare another XML message and send it to a REST service to obtain jobToken
4. loop:
    
   4.1. aggregate messages from 2nd JMS queue in batches of 1000, stop aggregation at timeout
    
   4.2. for every batch, convert it to CSV file
   4.3. send csv via HTTP Post to a REST service 
   4.4. retain batchtoken assigned to each batch
5. using the jobtoken prepare XML message and send to REST service to commit the batches
6. using batchtoken check execution status of each batch via XML message to REST service

While looking at Camel I could create a sample project where I can model out the exchange 1-3, 5:

```
           from("file:src/data?noop=true")
                .setHeader("sfUsername", constant("a@fd.com"))
                .setHeader("sfPwd", constant("12345"))
            .to("velocity:com/eip/vm/bulkPreLogin.vm?contentCache=false")
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/xml; charset=UTF-8"))
                .setHeader("SOAPAction", constant("login"))
                .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
            .to("http4://bulklogin") // send login
            .to("xslt:com/eip/xslt/bulkLogin.xsl")  //xslt transformation to retrieve userToken
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String body = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                    String[] bodyParts = body.split(",");
                    exchange.getProperties().put("userToken", bodyParts[0]);
                    .....
                }
            })
            .to("velocity:com/eip/vm/jobInsertTeamOppStart.vm")
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/xml; charset=UTF-8"))
                .setHeader("X-Session", property("userToken"))
                .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
            .to("http4://scheduleJob")       //schedule job
            .to("xslt:com//eip/xslt/jobInfoTransform.xsl")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String body = (String) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                    exchange.getProperties().put("jobToken",body.trim());
                }
            })
            //add batches in a loop ???
            .to("velocity:com/eip/vm/jobInsertTeamOppEnd.vm")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("https://na15.com/services/async/job/${property.jobToken}"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/xml; charset=UTF-8"))
                .setHeader("X-ID-Session", property("userToken"))
                .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
            .to("http4://closeJob")       //schedule job
            //check batch?
            .bean(new SomeBean());
```

So, my question is: 
How can I read messages from my 2nd JMS queue?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't strike me as a very good use-case for a single camel route. I think you should implement the main functionality in a POJO and use Camels Bean Integration for consuming and producing messages. This will result in much more easy to maintain code, and also for easier Exception handling.

See https://camel.apache.org/pojo-consuming.html

Comment: Having entire process logic implemented with beans then puts under a question the use of Camel in this project. Whell... I'm just learning and while the @consume annotation just registers a valid consumer, what I was looking for is the solution to start consuming  a queue upon some signal, not upon the onMessage event. I appreciate your answer, though.